# Count each word within a string

Tags: algorithm, php, strings

I am looking for a solution with fewer lines of code. This is code that is working perfectly, but I think I typed too much for this algorithm. If I did something wrong, feel free to tell me the error.

### Code

```
    <?php
    function Clearstring(string $string) 
    {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[,.!;?]/',"",$string);
    return $string;
    }   

    function CountString($string){
        $textsplit = preg_split("/\s/",$string);
        $wordsArray = [];
        $array= [];
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($textsplit as $word){
            try{
                $word = Clearstring($word);
                if(in_array($word,$array))
                {
                    if(in_array($wordsArray[$word],$wordsArray))
                    { 
                    $wordsArray[$word] +=1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    array_push($array,$word);
                    $counter =0;
                    $wordsArray[$word] = $counter;
                    if(in_array($wordsArray[$word],$wordsArray))
                    { 
                        $wordsArray[$word] +=1;
                    }
                }
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            echo "It has occurred the next error ".$ex;
        }
    }
    print_r($wordsArray);
    }
    CountString('Hello, I don`t know who I am but I know who you are, but I don`t know where I am');
?>
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [hello] => 1
    [i] => 5
    [don`t] => 2
    [know] => 3
    [who] => 2
    [am] => 2
    [but] => 2
    [you] => 1
    [are] => 1
    [where] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can competely avoid rolling your own code for this task.  PHP offers a solution via just two native function calls.

Ask [`str_word_count()`](https://www.php.net/str_word_count) to return all words found using `1` as the second parameter AND nominate the backtick as an acceptable character within words.

Then call [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_count_values) to group the encountered words and find their total occurrences.

...How considerate of PHP to offer these tools for you!

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eAaDI))

```
$string = 'Hello, I don`t know who I "am" but I know who you are, but I don`t know where I am';
var_export(array_count_values(str_word_count($string, 1, '`')));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Hello' => 1,
  'I' => 5,
  'don`t' => 2,
  'know' => 3,
  'who' => 2,
  'am' => 2,
  'but' => 2,
  'you' => 1,
  'are' => 1,
  'where' => 1,
)
```

If you used standard apostrophes instead of backticks, you don't need to declare the 3rd parameter in `str_word_count()`.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/cM9h0)

```
$string = "Hello, I don't know who I \"am\" but I know who you are, but I don't know where I am";
var_export(array_count_values(str_word_count($string, 1)));
```

p.s. I see that I overlooked the `strtolower()` part.  Just call that inside `str_word_count()`.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for  your answer, I tried to do all by my own, but there were some functions to help me, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

## Review

Mick has suggested a solution with fewer lines of code. I would like to address some points about the existing code.

### Useless conditional

[image: narrow gate]

Inside the `else` block `0` is assigned to `$wordsArray[$word]`, then it checks to see if `$wordsArray[$word]` (which is `0`) is within `$wordsArray` - that will always be true.

> ```
> else{
>     array_push($array,$word);
>     $counter =0;
>     $wordsArray[$word] = $counter;
>     if(in_array($wordsArray[$word],$wordsArray))
>     { 
>         $wordsArray[$word] +=1;
>     }
> }
> ```

It could simply assign 1 to `$wordsArray[$word]`.

### Simpler array push

[image: stacking image]

In the aforementioned code block, `$word` is pushed into `$array`:

> ```
> array_push($array,$word);
> ```

When adding a single element to an array, the same can be achieved by assigning the next available key ([which can be omitted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)):

```
$array[] = $word;
```

### Post-increment operator

Also in both the `if` And `else` blocks there are lines to add one to the counts:

> ```
> $wordsArray[$word] +=1;
> ```

Those could be simplified using the [post-increment operator `++`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

```
$wordsArray[$word]++;
```

### Variable names

Names like `$array` aren't very descriptive of what they contain. A better name might be `$uniqueWords`.

### Function names

Many PHP programmers follow standards outlined in [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) like [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). PSR-1 states:

> Method names MUST be declared in `camelCase()`.

That should apply to function names as well. So idiomatic PHP code would use a name like `countString` instead of `CountString`

### Spacing

PSR-12 also describes spacing in various sections. For example, see [PSR-12 section 4.7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#47-method-and-function-calls):

> #### [4.7 Method and Function Calls](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#47-method-and-function-calls)
>
> When making a method or function call, there MUST NOT be a space between the method or function name and the
> opening parenthesis, there MUST NOT be a space after the opening
> parenthesis, and there MUST NOT be a space before the closing
> parenthesis. In the argument list, there MUST NOT be a space before
> each comma, and there MUST be one space after each comma.

And also [PSR-12 section 5](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures):

> #### [5. Control Structures](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures)
>
> The general style rules for control structures are as follows:
>
> - **There MUST be one space after the control structure keyword**
> - There MUST NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis
> - There MUST NOT be a space before the closing parenthesis
> - **There MUST be one space between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace**
> - The structure body MUST be indented once

So there should be a space after a `foreach`:

> ```
> foreach($textsplit as $word){
> ```

Should be:

```
foreach ($textsplit as $word) {
```

And similarly for `if` - like

> ```
> if(in_array($wordsArray[$word],$wordsArray))
> {
> ```

Should be:

```
if (in_array($wordsArray[$word], $wordsArray)) {
```

Also:

> #### [6.2. Binary operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators)
>
> All binary [arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [logical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), and [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space.

So Instead of this within the `else` block:

> ```
> $counter =0;
> ```

Add a space after the `=`:

```
 $counter = 0;
```

And as mentioned earlier that variable is only used once after it is used so it can be eliminated.

### Splitting string using regular expression

It is fine to use regular expressions but since it is just splitting on a single space [can be done faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303248/1575353) using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) - e.g.

> ```
> $textsplit = preg_split("/\s/",$string);
> ```

can be simply:

```
$textsplit = explode(' ', $string);
```

### Exception handling

The code echoes the exception:

> ```
> catch(Exception $ex){
>     echo "It has occurred the next error ".$ex;
> }
> ```

Notice that this is calling the [`Exception::__toString()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php), which may show more details than desired - e.g. the file, line, stack trace, etc. It may be appropriate to call the [`getMessage()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php), or else not show any details to the user and instead show a more generic message.

Comment: Man, thank you so much for those tips, give me some good advices, I appreciate that.

Comment: Your "simpler solution" also is a less efficient solution, making an otherwise linear time complexity quadratic. Furthermore I wonder about "subwords": Won't this count `foobar foo` as 2x `foo` and 1x `foobar` whereas it should count it as 1x `foobar` and 1x `foo`?

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up. You are correct about the potential for substrings counting multiple times. I have removed that solution.